# Target iPhone 6 plus to iPad app

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just got my iPhone 6 plus and noticed that a lot of the Apple apps are using the iPad version when rotating the phone to landscape. It makes sense since the screen is so large.

So my question is. How do I detect this in Xcode to target iPhone 6 plus phones to run the iPad version of my app?

Comment: The iPhone 6+ does not run the iPad version of any app. Why do you think that is true?

Comment: Try open Notes, Messages, Safari or Settings and rotate to landscape. They look a lot like a iPad version. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to detect. An app should be written so it doesn't really care what device it is on. Everything should be based on size classes and auto layout.

In the examples you mention (in the comments), most likely what you are seeing are UISplitViewControllers which looks similar on the iPhone 6+ as it does on the iPad.

Just write a proper universal app with one set of screens that properly adapt themselves based on the current size class.

Comment: Well i kind of agree. I've used auto layout and size classes but because of the small screen on iPhone 6 and below I don't want to enable some features that are available on iPad. We have an universal app where some screens simply isn't available on iPhone. So size classes won't help. The simple trick as I see but be to "trick" the app to think that it is running on an iPad. From there all my size classes and auto layout will work on the iPhone 6 plus

Comment: No, the proper solution is to base things on screen size, not on specific device. Think about your app running in split screen multitasking mode on an iPad. In that case your app should run just like it's on an iPhone. So never check the device.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess that makes sense. I think in my case I need to lock rotation for devices below iPhone 6 plus and show the "iPad version" when users rotate to landscape.